# Vue 3 and vite cors problems on prod

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, vuejs3, vite

I have site that was worked on vue 3 and vue-cli with nginx and proxy. So I change from vue-cli to vite v4 and now I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED here is my vite.config

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // "vue-i18n": "vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.cjs.js",
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  base: "/",
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 3000,
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    cors: false,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:3200",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        // ws: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I trying few weeks to fix but no success

I try without cors and try to implement all options for the vite configuration

Comment: Are you using vite in production?

Comment: Yes this is for production, on local its working everything.

Comment: Vite is a development tool that is nog meant for use in production. If you use `vite build` to make a production bundle, the proxy settings won't  work in production. https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#building-for-production

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem, the wrong set of env variables. In vite when importing the env variables with method import.meta it was not read the NODE_ENV so I need to add environment in the env file so the places where get base URL its read correctly by the environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).